# Ошибка TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Здравствуйте пишу бота в телегу и выскочила ошибка

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str (base) 192:korona kupuelel$

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import COVID19Py

covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19()
bot = telebot.TeleBot('лишний раз не пишу токен')

# Функция, что сработает при отправке команды Старт
# Здесь мы создаем быстрые кнопки, а также сообщение с привествием
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Во всём мире')
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Украина')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Россия')
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Беларусь')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)

    send_message = f"<b>Привет {message.from_user.first_name}!</b>\nЧтобы узнать данные про 
коронавируса напишите " \
        f"название страны, например: США, Украина, Россия и так далее\n\n"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

# Функция, что сработает при отправке какого-либо текста боту
# Здесь мы создаем отслеживания данных и вывод статистики по определенной стране
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def mess(message):
    final_message = ""
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip().lower()
    if get_message_bot == "сша":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("US")
    elif get_message_bot == "украина":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("UA")
    elif get_message_bot == "россия":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("RU")
    elif get_message_bot == "беларусь":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("BY")
    elif get_message_bot == "казакхстан":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("KZ")
    elif get_message_bot == "италия":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("IT")
    elif get_message_bot == "франция":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("FR")
    elif get_message_bot == "германия":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("DE")
    elif get_message_bot == "япония":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("JP")
    else:
        location = covid19.getLatest()
    final_message = f"<u>Данные по всему миру:</u>\n<b>Заболевших: </b>. 
{location['confirmed']:,}\n<b>Сметрей: </b>{location['deaths']:,}"

    if final_message == "":
        date = location[0]['last_updated'].split("T")
        time = date[1].split(".")
        final_message = f"<u>Данные по стране:</u>\nНаселение: {location[0] 
['country_population']:,}\n" \
                f"Последнее обновление: {date[0]} {time[0]}\nПоследние данные:\n<b>" \
                f"Заболевших: </b>{location[0]['latest']['confirmed']:,}\n<b>Сметрей: </b>" \
                f"{location[0]['latest']['deaths']:,}"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message, parse_mode='html')

# Это нужно чтобы бот работал всё время
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка выскакивает в 49 строке:

```
final_message = f"<u>Данные по всему миру:</u>\n<b>Заболевших: </b>{location['confirmed']:,}\n<b>Сметрей: </b>{location['deaths']:,}"
```

Comment: Очень жду ваши коменты

Comment: 49 строка это что?

Comment: Ну вы берете информацию из массива по строке, так делать нельзя, о чем вам и сообщает интерпретатор. Используйте срезы или целые числа.

Comment: Лучше всего воспользоваться отладчиком и прогнать код по шагам, на каждом шаге будет понятно, что чему равно и как этим пользоваться

Comment: У вас там ниже всё через  location[0] делается , может и тут нужно так же? Или вообще через location[0]['latest']. Покажите, что у вас в location лежит в этот момент, без этого только гадать можно.

Comment: @CraElf спасибо , но не получается я сделал как вы сказали location[0]['latest'] и выскачила ошибка KeyErroro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, используется эта [библиотека](https://pypi.org/project/COVID19Py/).

`covid19.getLatest()` возвращает `<class 'dict'>`:

```
import COVID19Py

covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19()

latest = covid19.getLatest()
print(latest, type(latest))

>>> {'confirmed': 4897492, 'deaths': 323285, 'recovered': 0} <class 'dict'>
```

Метод `dict.get(key[, default])` - возвращает значение ключа, но если его нет, не бросает исключение, а возвращает default (по умолчанию None).

Таким образом получить значение можно:

```
print('confirmed:', latest.get('confirmed'), 'deaths:', latest.get('deaths'), 'recovered:', latest.get('recovered'))

>>> confirmed: 4897492 deaths: 323285 recovered: 0
```